# Is recommended to use Sherlock Action Bar?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm working on an android project, in which i'm going to implement the tab layout, with **TabHost**, **Fragment**, and **ViewPager**. 
By the way, I found some tutorial about the **Sherlock Action Bar**, and here is my question:
Is better the "native" code, or use this library?

What's your experience about this topic? And what's your suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: ABS is for the pre 3 Android version. I read something to the developer website to use it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're going to target an Android SDK version < 11 (Honeycomb 3.0), ActionBarSherlock is definitely better than ActionBarCompat, the official solution for backwards compatibility offered by Google. Otherwise if you're developing using only APIs >= 11 use the default ActionBar because ABS implements nothing more than that.

[Here](http://corner.squareup.com/2012/05/actionbarsherlock-as-a-base.html) you can find an article written by Jake Wharton (the developer of ABS) where he discusses different ActionBar solutions pros and cons.

Comment: Roman Nurik actually apologized for ActionbarCompat. https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/TCaGvy8dFue

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer:

If you want your application to look the same, including the action bar... then yes. It is NOT frowned upon, and **Google** mentions ABS all the time. From Google I/O to meetups in New York. ABS is always a recommended way to get compatibility with older devices/versions.

Answer (score 0):

The Sherlock Action Bar is only to provide backwards support for API 10 and below. Above that you should use Action Bar since it was added in API 11 (3.0). So to answer your question, if you are targetting API 11 and up, use the native Action Bar, otherwise you will HAVE to use Action Bar Sherlock to get that look.

Here are the websites to both:

[Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

and

[Action Bar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)